# Excel Add-In - ClickOnce - VSTOInstaller.exe.config file, what is it?

Tags: excel, deployment, clickonce

**EDIT :** Looks like a Microsoft issue, see forum indicated by correct answer.

**EDIT 2:** I am going to stop monitoring this page, looks like the Microsoft forum is dead and I also don't work for the same company anymore.

---

We have a Excel Add-in (C# / .NET 4.0) which supports Excel 2007/2010/2013 and is deployed through Excel Add-In. Today, a new client ran into problems on a single machine (other machines installed the add-in correctly). The error was:

> The value of the property 'type' cannot be parsed. The error is: Could
>   not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.BusinessApplications.Fba,
>   Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or
>   one of its dependancies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   (C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\VSTO\10.0\VSTOInstaller.exe.Config line 10)

My buddy Google gave me a number of suggestions: We had the client try a repair of MS VSTO Tools for Office and a repair of Office, and had the IE cache cleared, but continued to get the same error. Finally, we tried re-naming the VSTOInstaller.**exe**.Config to 'hide' it from the installation and it appears to be working.

I don't believe that our Add-In or installation produces this file, and there is no dependancies on this file that I'm aware of (it appears to be related to a SharePoint assembly)

While I don't explicitly download the add-in myself (I run it through VS2013), I have a VSTOInstaller.config file (Note, not *.exe.config, as seen from client) which contains the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <webRequestModules>
      <remove prefix="http:"/>
      <remove prefix="https:"/>
      <add prefix="http:"
           type="Microsoft.Office.BusinessApplications.Runtime.DeploymentAction.HttpFbaRequestCreator,Microsoft.Office.BusinessApplications.Runtime,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
      <add prefix="https:"
           type="Microsoft.Office.BusinessApplications.Runtime.DeploymentAction.HttpFbaRequestCreator,Microsoft.Office.BusinessApplications.Runtime,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
    </webRequestModules>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

In order to get a better idea of why this client is getting the specified error, I'm looking into

1. Where this file could have come from.
2. How does it affect the installation.
3. Any other comments or general tips related to the exception, or better yet, how to avoid it altogether.

Comment: What version of Office was the client running?

Comment: I believe Excel 2010, but not 100% sure. Add-in should work with 2007/10/13

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to be a known issue which affects many users. Someone from Microsoft has jumped on the train. See [Microsoft support forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c26d3f76-be37-4e1b-9d9a-84edae351e18/problem-with-vstoinstallerconfig) where the current progress can be found.

Resolution by Microsoft seems not to be happening. There are several scripts around to fix it. We have added a "Fix It" button to our non-VSTO products. See [post](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/vstoinstallerexeconfig-causes-many-office-add-ons-fail-guido-leenders).

Comment: Nice to see some traction, we will see where it goes.

Answer (score 12):

Just try to rename the VSTOInstaller.exe.Config to VSTOInstaller.exe.Config.old and then run the setup

Comment: I was running into the above issue while trying to install an application. This solution saved my day. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Had same error when trying to install word-addin on a single machine. I suspect it has something to do with mixed versions of office applications. I have nerver had this problem before on any other machine, but on this specific one, Office 2013 was installed first, followed by Project 2010 and Visio 2010.

Renaming the VSTOInstaller.exe.Config file solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

Since I do not have enough points to add a Comment, I am posting an answer instead.

We were facing the same problems with our MS Word plugin when we tried to install as a regular non-admin user on a fresh machine. VSTOR was already installed through an earlier administrator task. So, I was not sure what was going on. These steps worked for me finally.

1. Login into the desktop with Administrator privileges.
2. Downloaded the setup.exe that was created by Visual Studio through
   the Publish action of Visual Stuio.
3. In our we are using the Web based deployment.
4. Unblocked the Setup.exe by clicking on Properties dialog.
5. I used "Run as administrator" and let the Setup.exe do its work.
6. Log back in as regular non-administrative user Download.
7. Setup.exe and install. It worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

We have same error when trying to install a Visio 2013-addin on a single machines where older versions of Visio have been installed. We have never had this problem before on any other machine, but now on numerous instances this is occurring as we update our Visio add-in to work in the newest version of Visio 2013. Office 2007 or 2010 and Visio 2007 or 2010 was installed first, followed by an upgrade to Visio 2013. Re-naming the VSTOInstaller.exe.Config to 'hide' it from the installation clears the error and our Visio 2013 add-in installs correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to run the setup.exe as an Administrator?
I think it'll fix your problem.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error above, but Running the setup published by Visual Studio as Administrator worked for me.